# Given edges in directed graph, if each edge is assigned to one node what is maximum number of edges that will be assigned?

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, graph-theory, directed-acyclic-graphs

Say there is a directed graph with 5 nodes with 4 edges in the format (a, b) where there is an edge from a to b.

```
edges = [(1, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3), (3, 5)]
```

Each edge will be assigned one of its node values, for example edge 1 (the (1, 2) edge) may be assigned the node 1 or 2. It will try to be assigned the first value, 1, and if that number was already assigned it will try to be assigned node 2. If 2 was already taken, edge 1 has no value. Find the maximum edges that are assigned some value and also a valid sequence of choosing which edges are assigned.

My approach pseudocode

```
function dfs (current node)
    if seen contains current node
        return
    for next node : graph[current node]
        if current node was not assigned to any edge before
            assign current node to the id of edge (current_node, next_node)
        if current node was assigned but next node was not
            assign next node to the id of edge (current_node, next_node)
        dfs(next_node)
seen = hashest
for num:all node
    if seen does not contain num and current node was not assigned to any edge
        dfs(num)
```

Although this works sometimes, it does not always find the maximum amount of edges. Sometimes, dfs ing from node 1 to n in order is not the optimal approach, or at least that is what I found using this code. Is there a constant time implementation or do I have to search by starting at different nodes? For example, using my code, lets say I started at edge 4, (3, 5). According to my algorithm,  edge (3,5) is assigned node 3. Then, say I started at edge 2, or (4, 1). Then, edge 2 is assigned node 4, and since edge 1, (1, 2), is a neighbor it is assigned node 1. However, this means edge (4,3) was not assigned to any node. And, it was in fact possible to assign nodes to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the graph is connected ( all nodes can be reached from one of the nodes ) then the maximum number of edges that can be assigned a number is `min( E, N )` where N is the number of nodes and E the number of edges

The algorithm is:

```
Copy graph, making all edges bidirectional
LOOP over edges in copy by using DFS
   IF src node unassigned, assign src to edge
   ELSE assign dst to edge
```

In your example suppose the 1-2 edge is looked at first, the result will be

```
1 - 2 < 1
1 - 4 < 4  ( 1 was assigned )
4 - 3 < 3
3 - 5 < 5
```

But if 1-4 is looked at first

```
1 - 4 < 1
4 - 3 < 4
3 - 5 < 3
1 - 2 < 2 ( 1 was assigned )
```

BTW, if the graph is NOT connected, then the algorithm can be applied to each component.

Comment: `A--B--C`... max = 2, not 3

Comment: This is better than my answer if you can prove it.

Comment: Actually, I can prove it, so this is better than my answer :-)

Comment: The proof is trivial.  If graph is connected then every node must have an edge.  The only reason that node's number cannot be assigned to an edge is your case, where there are less edges than nodes

Comment: Thank you. Follow up question, not mentioned in original question. Is there a way to print the optimal order of edges to traverse while having maximum number of edges? For example, for the input case, one optimal traversal path is choosing edges 2, 1, 3, 4. However, first picking 4, 2, 1 is not optimal since now the 3rd edge has nowhere to go.

Comment: There is no optimal order.  The correct algorithm ( I have added it to my answer ) will work no matter what order the edges are looked at.

Comment: `1-2` < 1, `3-4` < 3, `1-3` < ?

Comment: There is no 1-3 edge

Comment: No DFS would visit edges in the order you suggest

Comment: Yes.  Look at the first step of the algorithm!

Comment: DFS order doesn't always work, either... but I think I should stop thinking of counter-examples now.

Comment: Without a counter example you cannot claim it doesn't work.

Comment: That's not really my goal.  This problem is a little more interesting that you give it credit for, and while it's not important that your "trivial proof" isn't a proof to me (what constitutes a proof is subjective), it's important that it's not a valid proof for you either.  I don't want to invalidate your *correct* answer to the question that was asked, but I think you could have fun adjusting your notion of "proof" in the process of finding a real one.

Comment: Not sure, but I suspect that hidden amongst all those words there may lurk an insult.

Comment: not at all, I assure you